# EC2 CPU Credit Balance: Why are there gaps in my credit balance graph?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I use CloudWatch to monitor dozens of aspects of our platform's ecosystem, and occasionally we'll have a machine that does this:

[image: graph of cpu credit balance]

Why are there gaps in this green line? The other instances being monitored during this time don't have gaps like this one.

Comment: Gaps generally represent no data, which happens for example when the instance is turned off. I don't remember seeing it in CPU credit balance when the instance was running fine. If you have a lot of servers you probably have AWS support - did you ask them?

Comment: This box is a Windows Server and as far as we know was otherwise fine overnight. That graph represents late night yesterday through early this morning and we definitely would have known if it wasn't serving its purpose during those hours. We don't have any direct access to support, but I have not filed a ticket yet to ask about it. I guess I should do that.

Comment: same thing happened to me today. it also causes the credit balance for the autoscaling group that the instance is in to drop to zero :(